# AWK print matching string with if-then and AND/OR operators

Tags: awk

Idea: Read pipe delimited input file, print multiple fields from each input line based on multiple field matching criteria.

Input Sample:

```
Game1=BasketBall|Game2=BaseBall|Game3=RaquetBall
Game5=MMA|Game2=Judo|Game6=Boxing
Game1=Horseplay|Game2=CouchSurfing|Game7=Texting
```

Logic: print out comma separated list of all "Key=Value" pairs with Game1 and Game2 as key names.

Output Sample:

```
Game1=BasketBall, Game2=BaseBall
Game2=Judo
Game1=Horseplay,Game2=CouchSurfing
```

I am not able to get any results from the following command:

```
cat 20200109.txt | awk -F"|" '{ for(i=0;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /Game1=/ || $i ~ /Game2=/ ) {print $i} } }' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First remember that fields numbers start at 1, so change your for loop accordingly:

```
awk -F"|" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /Game1=/ || $i ~ /Game2=/ ) {print $i} } }'
```

With that you get:

```
Game1=BasketBall
Game2=BaseBall
Game2=Judo
Game1=Horseplay
Game2=CouchSurfing
```

Which is close. To avoid the newline after every match, use printf instead:

```
 $ awk -F"|" '{ comma=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /Game1=/ || $i ~ /Game2=/ ) {printf "%s%s", comma, $i; comma=","} } print ""}' file
 Game1=BasketBall,Game2=BaseBall
 Game2=Judo
 Game1=Horseplay,Game2=CouchSurfing
```